# RawJsonValues in Unity & Firebase

Tags: c#, firebase, unity-game-engine, firebase-realtime-database

Some problems with the `SetRawJsonValueAsync`. When I use the code from documentation:

```
    public class User
{
    public string username;
    public string email;

    public User()
    {
    }

    public User(string username, string email)
    {
        this.username = username;
        this.email = email;
    }
}

private void writeNewUser(string userId, string name, string email)
{
    User user = new User(name, email);
    string json = JsonUtility.ToJson(user);

    mDatabaseRef.Child("users").Child(userId).SetRawJsonValueAsync(json);
}
```

Then firebase automatically converts it to the tree of values. Ok. But when i'm trying to get them back:

```
    public void get_data()
{
    mDatabaseRef.Child("users").Child(userId).GetValueAsync().ContinueWithOnMainThread(task => {
        if (task.IsCompleted)
        {
            Debug.Log("completed");
            string json = task.Result.Value;
            User user = JsonUtility.FromJson<User>(json);
            Debug.Log(user.username);
        }
    });
}
```

it stops and doesn't print username. Why? Or how i need to get json raws?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The issue here is [`task.Result.Value`](https://firebase.google.com/docs/reference/unity/class/firebase/database/data-snapshot#class_firebase_1_1_database_1_1_data_snapshot_1a45e32265ebf6ad5ee66848b425e9a934) is a C# interpretation of the value in the database. I believe it should be a `IDictionary<string, object>` given the code that you posted.

What you want is [`task.Result.GetRawJsonValue()`](https://firebase.google.com/docs/reference/unity/class/firebase/database/data-snapshot#getrawjsonvalue):

```
public void get_data()
{
    mDatabaseRef.Child("users").Child(userId).GetValueAsync().ContinueWithOnMainThread(task => {
        if (task.IsCompleted)
        {
            Debug.Log("completed");
            string json = task.Result.GetRawJsonValue();
            User user = JsonUtility.FromJson<User>(json);
            Debug.Log(user.username);
        }
    });
}
```

Comment: Thanks a lot! And can I serialize MonoBehavior scripts by this way (i mean using Json), because adding `: MonoBehaviour` leads to some problems.

Comment: If you want to fill out a MonoBehaviour, you need to initialize it on your own (either with `GameObject.Instantiate`, `GameObject.GetComponent`, or `GameObject.AddComponent`) since the constructor is kind of invalid for MonoBehaviour in Unity. Then you can use `JsonUtility.FromJsonOverwrite`. Note that you'll always miss `Awake` and sometimes miss `Start` this way, so it can make it hard to do this safely 

https://docs.unity3d.com/ScriptReference/JsonUtility.FromJsonOverwrite.html

Comment: Cheers! It is helpful 